# Colecciones dentro de documentos en firebase y angular 7

Tags: firebase, angular, angular5

tengo el siguiente código para obtener dos observables en uno y poder manipularlos.

```
public products: any;


ngOnInit() {
        this.products = this.productService.products().snapshotChanges().map(productSnaps => {
          return productSnaps.map(product => {
            const productData = product.payload.doc.data();
            const productId = product.payload.doc.id;
            return this.productService.getProductImages(productId).snapshotChanges().map(uploadSnap => {
              let number = 0;
              return uploadSnap.map(upload => {
                if(number == 0) {
                  number++;
                  return upload.payload.doc.data();
                }
              })
            })
            .map(uploads => {
              return {productId, ...productData, uploads: uploads};
            })
          })
        })
        .flatMap(products => Observable.combineLatest(products));
      }
```

los servicios de products() y getProductImages() son los siguientes:

```
type productsCollection = AngularFirestoreCollection<Product[]>;

products(): productsCollection {
    return this.afs.collection<Product[]>('products');
  }

getProductImages(productId: string) {
    return this.afs.doc<Product>(`products/${productId}`).collection('uploads');
  }
```

Tengo una base en firebase con la siguiente estructura:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no me compila con rxjs 6, intenté hacerlo así:

```
ngOnInit() {    
    this.products = this.productService.products().snapshotChanges().pipe(map(productSnaps => {      
        return productSnaps.map(product => {          
          const productData = product.payload.doc.data();
          const productId = product.payload.doc.id;

          return this.productService.getProductImages(productId).snapshotChanges().pipe(map(uploadSnap => {
              let number = 0;
              return uploadSnap.map(upload => {
                if (number === 0) {
                  number++;
                  return upload.payload.doc.data();
                }
              });
            }),
            map(uploads => {
              return {productId, ...productData, uploads: uploads};
            })
          );
        });

      })
    ).flatMap(products => Observable.combineLatest(products));    
  }
```

Pero marca error el flatMap y el combineLatest

Lo que al final de cuentas necesito es que en la variable products se almacenen tanto los documentos de la collection "products" como la collection que esta dentro de cada documento y que contiene las imágenes de estos.

y poder utilizarlos así:

```
<img height="250" *ngIf="product.uploads[0]" mat-card-image [src]="product.uploads[0].url" />
<mat-card-title>{{ product.name }}</mat-card-title>
```

de antemano muchas gracias

Answer (score 2):

Después de tanto hacer pruebas esta es la forma que me dio resultado y quiero compartirla, saludos y gracias.

```
onInit() {
   this.products = this.productService.products(tipo).snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(productSnaps => {      
        return productSnaps.map(product => {          
          const productData = product.payload.doc.data();
          const productId = product.payload.doc.id;

          return this.productService.getProductImages(productId).snapshotChanges().pipe(
            map(uploadSnap => {
              let number = 0;
              return uploadSnap.map(upload => {
                if (number === 0) {
                  number++;
                  return upload.payload.doc.data();
                }
              });
            }),
            map(uploads => {

              return {productId, ...productData, uploads: uploads};

            })
          );
        });

      }),
      flatMap(products => combineLatest(products))
    );
}
```

Espero les sirva como a mi!